# Clients getting sent wrong Term Serv CAL, getting Temp instead of installed CAL

Tags: windows-server-2008, licensing, remote-desktop-services

I have Win Server 2008R2 with RDS role and then another 2008R2 DC that is also the license server. When I first installed the RDS server I did not have CAL licenses at the time so the users were getting temp per device CAL. A few days later I installed the PER USER CAL on the server. How can I move the users from the temp CAL to the ones I bought?

[Screen shot of RD Licensing Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkNGV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell your terminal servers where the license server is in the Terminal server config, or better still there's a policy you can set (i cant remember where it is exactly) that you can use to set the info on mass.

Also for info we have had some issues in the past on XP machines where if a user has a temporary license, they don't always end up with a full one. We traced it down a a problem with a permission on a registry key, but to fix it you just have to logonto the machine as a local admin, then connect twice (it has to be twice, and you dont need to logon) to a terminal server.